# Insert XML element to a specific location using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to insert aaa into the parent "holding category" like the following:

```
<ns2:holding category="BASIC">
      <ns2:pieceDesignation>10010194589</ns2:pieceDesignation>
      <temporaryLocation>aaa</temporaryLocation>
      <ns2:cost>
```

Here's the code I've written:

```
 temporarylocation = Element("temporaryLocation")`
 temporarylocation.text = 'aaa'
 holdingcategory.insert(1,temporarylocation)
 print(ET.tostring(holdingcategory))
```

However, the the result I've received looks like this:

```
<ns2:pieceDesignation>10010194589</ns2:pieceDesignation>
    <temporaryLocation>aaa</temporaryLocation><ns2:cost>
```

with ns2:cost followed immediately after temporaryLocation instead of 
starting from the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ElementTree doesn't do "pretty printing" so if you want readable indentation you need to add it yourself.  I created an XML snippet similar to yours for illustration.  The `indent` function was obtained from an example on the ElementTree author's website [(link)](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm#prettyprint):

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

xml = '''\
<doc>
  <holding category="BASIC">
    <pieceDesignation>10010194589</pieceDesignation>
  </holding>
</doc>'''

tree = et.fromstring(xml)
holdingcategory = tree.find('holding')
temporarylocation = et.Element("temporaryLocation")
temporarylocation.text = 'aaa'
holdingcategory.insert(1,temporarylocation)
et.dump(tree)

def indent(elem, level=0):
    i = "\n" + level*"  "
    if len(elem):
        if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
            elem.text = i + "  "
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
        for elem in elem:
            indent(elem, level+1)
        if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
            elem.tail = i
    else:
        if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
            elem.tail = i

indent(tree)
print()
et.dump(tree)
```

Output:

```
<doc>
  <holding category="BASIC">
    <pieceDesignation>10010194589</pieceDesignation>
  <temporaryLocation>aaa</temporaryLocation></holding>
</doc>

<doc>
  <holding category="BASIC">
    <pieceDesignation>10010194589</pieceDesignation>
    <temporaryLocation>aaa</temporaryLocation>
  </holding>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This just gives me what I've wanted.